# How to use Java subclasses

Tags: java, object, methods, abstract-class, extends

I have 3 classes, Book, ChildrensBook and Library. ChildrensBook extends the Book class.
ChildrensBook contains the additional variable recommendedAge.
Library contains an array that can include both Book and ChildrensBook objects.
In the class Library I have to create the method int forChildren(int n) that returns how many childrensBook of age less or equal to n are there in array Library.
the problem is that in the library array there are both Books and ChildrensBooks, so I can't access the recommendedAge variable, because it is only inside a children's book. how can I do?

```
public class Library {
    private ArrayList <Book> collection;

    public Library(ArrayList <Book> c){
        collection=c;
    }

    public int forChildren(int n) {
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<collection.size();i++) {
            if((collection.get(i).getRecommendedAge)<=n) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

public class Book {
    private String title;
    private String author;

    public Book(String title, String author){
        this.title=title;
        this.author=author;
    }

}

public class ChildrensBook extends Book {
    private int recommendedAge;

    public ChildrensBook(String title,String author,int recommendedAge){
        super(title,author);
        this.recommendedAge=recommendedAge;
    }
    public int getRecommendedAge() {
        return recommendedAge;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can first check if the element is an *instance of* a ChildrensBook (`if (collection.get(i) instanceof ChildrensBook)` and then *typecast* the element to the ChildrensBook type using `ChildrensBook cb = (ChildrensBook) collection.get(i)`. Now `cb.recommendedAge` is accessible.

Answer (score 4):

Basically I see three possible approaches:

1. Pull the knowledge about recommended ages up to the `Book` class so that every book has a recommended age although you then need to decide which recommended age a non children's book has.
2. Decide on iterating over the books if a `Book` is a children's book or not - this can be achieved using Java's `instanceof` operator although this is not particularly object oriented.
3. Add a method similar to `isValidForAge` for books deciding if a book is valid for a certain given ages or not which every children's book answers based on the recommended age and every non children's book needs to answer based on other criteria.

Comment: The exact points I wanted to post :) I'd go with the first one, any book can fall into a certain age category. Age category could mean more than an integer, e.g. 18+ (age of majority), 3- (toddlers)

Answer (score 1):

This is improper class design.
You mixed a concern of books classification (children, adult, science-fiction, humor) which is more like a category or "tag" and the particular behavior (which is suitability for the audience).

You may decide to make a Book class abstract and inherit a concrete AdultBook class from it.
As already mentioned in other answer, you could have an adult book which is still suitable for children. Let's say a biography or an encyclopedia.

Which means, you may want to exercise `getRecommendedAge()` on every book in your collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `instanceof` operator to check the type of the object. Try the below code:

```
public class Library {
    private ArrayList<Book> collection;

    public Library(ArrayList<Book> c) {
        collection = c;
    }

    public int forChildren(int n) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < collection.size(); i++) {
            if (collection.get(i) instanceof ChildrensBook) {
                if (((ChildrensBook) collection.get(i)).getRecommendedAge() <= n) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public class Book {
        private String title;
        private String author;

        public Book(String title, String author) {
            this.title = title;
            this.author = author;
        }

    }

    public class ChildrensBook extends Book {
        private int recommendedAge;

        public ChildrensBook(String title, String author, int recommendedAge) {
            super(title, author);
            this.recommendedAge = recommendedAge;
        }

        public int getRecommendedAge() {
            return recommendedAge;
        }
    }
```